# find & replace vba changes format of date

Tags: vba, excel, replace

I have a range of cells with dates, that contain values that have to be replaced. Once I do that using general Find & Replace - it works smoothly. When I do it in VBA, the formatting of the cells is changed and dates are converted to a wrong ones, e.g. 12/10/2015 (12 October), but become 10/12/2015 (10 December). Here's the code:

```
Sub find_replace()
ActiveSheet.Range("T1", Range("T1").End(xlToRight).Offset(0, -2)).Select
With Selection
.NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
.Replace What:="P.", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart,     SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False,   ReplaceFormat:=False
.Replace What:=".", Replacement:="/", LookAt:=xlPart,    SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False,    ReplaceFormat:=False
End With
End Sub
```

Please be so kind as to advise how to get rid of this annoying issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Date() I'm Italian and always quarrel with the date..
If the date that you want convert is alway like `P.01.10.2015` to 1th Oct
try the code below, otherwise change the start/end of `right(x,x)`,`mid(x,x,x)`

```
Sub find_replace()
Dim cell As Range
Dim yr As String, mnt As String, dy As String
Dim d As Date
For Each cell In ActiveSheet.Range("T1", Range("T1").End(xlToRight).Offset(0, -2))
yr = Right(cell, 4)
mnt = Mid(cell, 6, 2)
dy = Mid(cell, 3, 2)
d = DateSerial(yr, mnt, dy)
Range(cell.Address) = d
Next cell
End Sub
```

Comment: many thanks, kind sir. your code did it's job, however, I amended the yr = Right(cell, 4) line, since there were only 2 figure-value (2015 as 15). Containing 4 figures the code generated out of year 2000, 2001, etc.

Answer (score 1):

It's due to the `.NumberFormat`.  Try changing that to `.NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy"`

Edit: Also, maybe just comment out/remove that line, if it's totally unnecessary.

Edit2: The above isn't the issue.  What if, after you have run the macro and have the dates in `dd/mm/yyyy` format, you do Text to Columns? Highlight the dates, go to Data--> Text to Columns,  choose "Delimited" and leave as "Tab", but in the next screen (step 3 of 3), choose "Column data format" as "Date: MDY", and click "Finish".

Comment: unfortunately, but no. the format of the date is workable (dd/mm/yyyy), when I apply standard Find & Replace in Excel directly, not via VB.........
Edit to your edit: I tried removing this line - same.

Comment: It's not the number format. VBA defaults to the US regional interpretation whenever possible. You have to loop.

Comment: If I loop through 200 columns it takes ages. The code I'm showing here is part of a one huge code where automation takes place. Bringing loop into such basic task would be extremely inefficient. Is there any other workarounds...? I'm sure there is :(

Comment: @DmitryVasilyev - I updated my post with another option, using Text to Columns.  It's worked for me in the past, hopefully it can help here too.

Comment: If you load your data into an array, process it and then write it back to the sheet, I'd be surprised if it takes very long.

Comment: @BruceWayne I also tried your advise with text to columns - it works on manual basis. I included it into the loop, but it doesn't work, and produces TRUE argument for the next columns whilst changing date of the first cell (T1) in our case. could u advise please?  

For Each c In r
c.Value = c.TextToColumns(Destination:=Selection, DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=False, TrailingMinusNumbers:=True)
Next c

Comment: @Rory, could u be so kind as to help with the code...?

Comment: If using `TextToColumns`, you just call it as a method - you don't assign the result to the cell. It parses the cell for you

Answer (score 0):

Here's a loop sample per my comment earlier:

```
Sub ParseDates()
    Dim vData
    Dim rData                       As Range
    Dim x                           As Long
    Dim y                           As Long
    Dim stemp                       As String
    Set rData = ActiveSheet.Range("T1", Range("T1").End(xlToRight).Offset(0, -2))
    vData = rData.Value2
    For x = LBound(vData, 1) To UBound(vData, 1)
        For y = LBound(vData, 2) To UBound(vData, 2)
            stemp = Replace$(Replace$(vData(x, y), "P.", ""), ".", "/")
            If IsDate(stemp) Then vData(x, y) = CDate(stemp)
        Next y
    Next x
    rData.Value2 = vData

End Sub
```

Comment: thanks a bunch, Rory. your code works brilliantly as well as Fabrizio's. I slightly amended it, added rData.NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy" as it provided date in format of days after 1900 year.